# I need a gtm tag to be fired when a successful api call is done

Tags: angular, google-tag-manager

I need to create a GTM (Google Tag manager) tag to be fired when an api call is done and the result is success (code: 200).
The api is called on a button click.
I don't want to write any code in my Angular project (like "sending data to the Data Layer" solution)

I have searched a lot, but I haven't found any useful solution. I would really appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTTP intercepter might be your solution?

-> https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

*-- More explanation --*

I guess GTM is already added to your angular project?

If yes you can add an Interceptor.
The Intercepter intercept every single api call.
So you could pass the value of that you want after every API call

Let us call that file gtm.interceptor.ts

```
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MessagesCenterInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }

    /**
     * If the user accept or decline a message, we set the message in the header/dashboard to true
     * @param request 
     * @param next 
     */
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            response => {
                // Here your GTM funktion. 
                // It's a little bit tricky and has be tested. I recommend to ask again another developer.
            }
        );
    }
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible for you to add more explanation?

Comment: I just explained more, but I don't know how you already have GTM added.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one helper service in which you can have code like this.

Inject **GoogleTagManagerService** in the constructor.

```
constructor( private gtmService: GoogleTagManagerService ) { }
```

Now create one Function for firing the event manually.

```
customEvents(eventName: string, eventData: any) {
        const gtmTag = {
          event: eventName,
          data: eventData,
        };
        this.gtmService.pushTag(gtmTag);
      }
```

And after the response of your API, you can hit it manually like this.

Example :

```
const result= await this.httpService.post('path', data);
if (result){
this.helperService.customEvents(GTM_CUSTOM_EVENT.BUTTON_CLICK_EVENT, GTM_CUSTOM_EVENT.PAYMENT_SUCCESS_REGISTERED_USER);
}
```

PS: - Here I have used a constant file to manage strings for events and data.

Comment: Thank you Manish, but do you have any idea how to do it in gtm panel, like custom Html snippet or something? Cuz as I said, I shouldn't write any codes.